# Probability of having three boys and three girls if at least one child is a girl

Tags: probability

Mr A has six children and at least one child is a girl , what is the probability that Mr A has $3$ boys and $3$ girls?

my try

Total cases are $6$

so probability should be $\frac{1}{6}$

but the answer is $\frac{20}{63}$.

Comment: The $6$ cases don't have the same probability.  Hint;  to get started, try to solve the same problem with two children instead of $6$.  (the answer is not $\frac 12$).

Comment: If you want each case to have equal probability, then the total number of cases is $64-1 = 63$. Or, you could argue that the total number of cases is $6$, but then they do not have the same probability.

Comment: Did you get this question from todays Score  - Allen Career Institute?

Comment: @lulu I could not understand why it is not (1/2) as there are only two cases . (G,G) and (G,B)

Comment: @JaideepKhare yes , have you also given that . http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54160/jee-preparation

Comment: Same as with $6$ kids, the cases don't have the same probability.  Try flipping a coin two times and count the various things that you get.

Comment: @lulu wait , I could not understand the case of 2 kids

Comment: As I say, try it with coins.  To clarify the situation, suppose you tossed first a penny, then a dime.  There are $4$ possible outcomes (and these do have the same probability!).  Just list them.

Comment: @lulu   http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55210/discussion-between-jaideep-khare-and-hey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The order of ages of children matters.**

Total cases : Since each child can be either girl or boy ; total cases will be

$2^6-1$

I have subtracted one for that case where each baby is a boy.

Favourable cases : We want $3$ child to be Boys and $3 $ girls.Since order does matter, we will have to permute $3 $ Boys and $3₹ Girls, i.e.

$$\frac {6!}{3!3!}=20$$

Probability = Favourable cases/Total cases

Probability  $ = \dfrac {20}{63}$

Comment: what mistake I have done

Comment: how did you find total cases to be 6?They aren't

Comment: (3G,3b) , (4g,2b) ,(5g,b) ,(6g), (2g,4b) , (1g,5b)

Comment: Read the Note in my answer ; order matters

Comment: how do we know about order

Comment: If you have 1G,5B , there are 6 cases in that too, The girl is eldest, on 2nd postion (second oldest) , 3rd ..so on...and youngest.

Comment: in the question it is not written age matters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55210/discussion-between-jaideep-khare-and-hey).

Comment: Of course the solution makes the assumption that a child is boy or girl with exactly the same probability (in reality, boys are slightly more probable), as well as the assumption that the sex of the different children is statistically independent of each other (I don't know if in reality this is the case).

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem in conditional probability: the probability that there are three girls given that there is at least one girl.  Let $G$ be the total number of girls in the family.  Then, by the definition of conditional probability,
$$\begin{align}
\Pr(G=3 \;|\; G \ge 1) &= \frac{\Pr((G=3) \; \cap \; (G \ge 1))}{\Pr(G \ge 1)} \\
&= \frac{\Pr(G=3)}{\Pr(G \ge 1)} \\
&= \frac{\Pr(G=3)}{1-\Pr(G = 0)} \\
&= \frac{\binom{6}{3} (1/2)^6}{1-(1/2)^6}
\end{align}$$